# Pandas - count percentage of group size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Say, I have the data like this:

```
col1   col2 other columns..
0      0    ...
0      0    ...
0      0    ...
0      0    ...
0      0    ...
0      0    ...
0      0    ...
0      0    ...
0      0    ...
0      0    ...
0      1    ...
0      1    ...
0      1    ...
0      1    ...
0      1    ...
0      1    ...
1      0    ...
1      0    ...
etc...
```

Data has been grouped by 2 columns (it's already result by grouping):

```
gr = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size()

col1   col2        
0      0           10
       1           5
1      0           2
       1           16
2      0           10
```

So now I need to figure out which percentage of each subgroup the count has respectively the whole group by 2 columns:

I need to add one more column, or transform to Series (better) to have a percentage of col2 respectively the group (col1) like:

```
       col1        col2
0      0           0.66
       1           0.33
1      0           0.1
       1           0.9
2      0           1
```

Or it can be separate Series for each group: `[0.66 0.1 1]` and `[0.33 0.9]`.
How to implement it?

So let me describe the meaning of this data. For example it can be subjects (0,1,2), results (0 or 1) and amount students per subject per result.
So the whole idea is to figure out what percentage of students failed/passed for subjects 0,1, etc.

One more additional thing - sometimes there is only one result (0 or 1) like the subject that all students passed, and I still need to be able to tell that for this subject percentage of 0 is 0,0 and of 1 is 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level of index with  [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
gr = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size()
print (gr)
col1  col2
0     0       10
      1        5
1     0        2
      1       16
2     0       10
dtype: int64

print (gr.groupby(level=0).sum())
col1
0    15
1    18
2    10
dtype: int64

print (gr / gr.groupby(level=0).sum())
col1  col2
0     0       0.666667
      1       0.333333
1     0       0.111111
      1       0.888889
2     0       1.000000
dtype: float64
```

For storing `Series` use dict comprehension:

```
dfs = {i:g.reset_index(drop=True) for i, g in g1.groupby(level=1)}

print (dfs[0])
0    0.666667
1    0.111111
2    1.000000
dtype: float64

print (dfs[1])
0    0.333333
1    0.888889
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. But I believe I described the task wrong, let me add more details and correct the mistakes. My apologies. Please look at updated question.

Comment: Solution changed, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,0,1,0],'B':[10,5,2,16,10]}, index=[0,1,0,1,0])
df2 = df.ix[0] / df.ix[0].sum()
df3 = df.ix[1] / df.ix[1].sum()
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Please see the updated post.